# Why doesn't self condensation occur in acetoacetic ester synthesis

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, esters

So, I came across a quite versatile method to synthesize aldehydes and ketones, its called the Acetoacetic ester synthesis.

Suppose I need some 2-pentanone. So to synthesize it via this method I can do this

[image]

But I'm more worried about adding a base to Acetoacetic ester. Won't self condensation occur between two molecules of Acetoacetic ester like this?

[image]

If it occurs how do we minimize it? If it doesn't then why?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't happen. You just get proton exchange.

Comment: Can you tell me the reason, please?

Comment: If the addition occurred at all AAE anion would prefer the ketone, a reaction that forms an intermediate alkoxide, whose conjugate acid has pKa ~15-18. The pKa of AAE is ~11. Seems to be an uphill battle.

Comment: @user55119 But I've learned that addition to ketones would require special conditions (i.e addition to ketones is mostly unfavourable due to steric hinderence).

Comment: I disagree. Addition of what to ketones? Grignard reagents? Stobbe condensation? Wittig reaction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Self-condensation is typically not an issue with 1,3-dicarbonyl compounds, such as the one in your question. Why? Due to their acidity ($\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ around 9 to 11), most 1,3-dicarbonyls exist in their enolate form in solution. Therefore, there is very little of the original electrophilic 1,3-dicarbonyl which the enolate can attack. Hence, the amount of self-condensation taking place is relatively little and usually not a concern.